# 'Type 'Color' is not a subtype of 'MaterialColor' error appears every time I build my Flutter app on the simulator (Android and iOS) in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, colors

I'm putting together a demo app, to help me learn various features of Flutter but at the moment, I am experiencing a recurring error I have not come across before.

Each time I build the app in Android Studio on any simulator (Android or iOS) an error is generated:

**Type 'Color' is not a subtype of type 'MaterialColor'**

Here is the exception and console output:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           16.9s
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown building MyApp(dirty):
flutter: type 'Color' is not a subtype of type 'MaterialColor'
flutter:
flutter: Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
flutter: more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
flutter: In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
flutter:   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
flutter:
flutter: The relevant error-causing widget was:
flutter:   MyApp
flutter:   file:///Users/JGolding/Desktop/Desktop/Work/App-and-Web-Development/App-Development/1-Demo-App/demo_app/lib/main.dart:4:23
flutter:
flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
flutter: #0      MyApp.build (package:demoapp/main.dart:13:35)
flutter: #1      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4291:28)
flutter: #2      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4223:15)
flutter: #3      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
flutter: #4      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
flutter: #5      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
flutter: #6      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
flutter: #7      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
flutter: #8      RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1028:16)
flutter: #9      RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:999:5)
flutter: #10     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:942:17)
flutter: #11     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2412:19)
flutter: #12     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:941:13)
flutter: #13     WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:819:7)
flutter: #14     WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:804:7)
flutter: #23     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:384:19)
flutter: #24     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:418:5)
flutter: #25     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:174:12)
flutter: (elided 8 frames from package dart:async and package dart:async-patch)
flutter:
flutter: ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60030/z8ejaMsnyI0=/ws
Syncing files to device iPhone 11 Pro Max...
```

This seems to suggest that the issue is in the `main.dart` file, which is here:

```
import 'package:demoapp/screens/home/home_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo App',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.blue[200],
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

At the moment, in `ThemeData()` I am using `primaryColor: Colors.blue[200]`. For some reason, the app builds if I change that to `primarySwatch: Colors.blue` and then back again to `primaryColor: Colors.blue[200]`. This has never happened to me before and I'm not sure why it keeps happening on the first build of the app in the simulator. Why might this be happening? Is there a way to sort it?

I am using `primaryColor` since I want to use that specific shade of blue as the main color. If this is an issue with `primaryColor`, is there perhaps a way to use `primarySwatch` and be able to select the specific color in a family?

Comment: primaryColor: Colors.blue[200], should work.

Comment: i tried `class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo App',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.blue[200],
      ),
      home: Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(), body: Text('FOO')),
    );
  }
}` in the https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ and it works just fine - note i added `Scaffold` as `home` property

Comment: Thanks guys. That's what I'm thinking. It There's no reason why it shouldn't work. Indeed, it does work once I change `primaryColor` to `primarySwatch`, build (throwing another error) and then back to `primaryColor`. Could it just be an issue with a recent date, or the simulator/emulator?

Comment: whats the output of `flutter --version` command? did you run my modified code? if so, the same result?

Comment: Yes I ran your code and no problem at all. It's very strange. So, the output of `flutter --version` is `Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.8 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 0b8abb4724 (4 weeks ago) • 2020-02-11 11:44:36 -0800
Engine • revision e1e6ced81d
Tools • Dart 2.7.0` .

Answer (score 34):

If you want to use custom color from hex like this color 0xFF0E7AC7

```
const MaterialColor kPrimaryColor = const MaterialColor(
  0xFF0E7AC7,
  const <int, Color>{
    50: const Color(0xFF0E7AC7),
    100: const Color(0xFF0E7AC7),
    200: const Color(0xFF0E7AC7),
    300: const Color(0xFF0E7AC7),
    400: const Color(0xFF0E7AC7),
    500: const Color(0xFF0E7AC7),
    600: const Color(0xFF0E7AC7),
    700: const Color(0xFF0E7AC7),
    800: const Color(0xFF0E7AC7),
    900: const Color(0xFF0E7AC7),
  },
);

theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: kPrimaryColor,
),
```